# Checkbox value not being set

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

In my database there's a bool fiedd called `IsAvailable`.In my edit function i wanted to fill that checkbox is `IsAvailable` or `not` but in here always checkbox not filled.

```
($("#chkcomp").prop('checked') == msg._prodlng[0].IsAvailable);
```

but

```
msg._prodlng[0].IsAvailable // this one returns true or false correctly according to database value
```

Comment: Where do you set the checkbox to be checked?

Comment: This question really doesnt make sense, you cant use == to assign, I don't understand what you want to do, please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax to set prop is:

```
$('el').prop('property','value');
```

So use,

```
$("#chkcomp").prop('checked',msg._prodlng[0].IsAvailable);
```